# Compare and retrieve information using sub-queries

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I got stuck at this problem.

There are three separate tables needed for this problem, with relevant information as follows

```
   copies table                rentalrates table             movies table

movienum rentalcode            rentalcode  rate       movienum     title   yearreleased  

 1000        D                      D       10          1000       Matrix     2001
 ...         D                     WN       12           ...        ...        ...
 ...         WN                    WL       15           ...        ...        ...
```

So I am required to display the output of "the title and year released of the movie that has the lowest rental rate" using sub queries, and "order by" is not allowed here.

final output like

title  yearreleased rate
matrix  2001         10

My trouble is I don't really know hot to compare the rate and select those movies of the lowest rates.

Any help or hint is extremely appreciated :)

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select min(rate) from rentalrates
```

will yield the minimum rental rate.  To go one step further, this query:

```
select m.title        as title,
       m.yearreleased as yearreleased,
       r.rate         as rate
  from copies      as c,
       rentalrates as r,
       movies      as m
 where c.movienum   = m.movienum
   and r.rentalcode = c.rentalcode
   and r.rate       = select min(rate) from rentalrates;
```

will display any movies (title, year, rate) where the rate is the lowest rate in the database.

Comment: thanks very much bro. it works! but you have made a small mistake here: the"r.rentalcode = m.rentalcode" should be "r.rentalcode = c.rentalcode" thank you though! cheers!

Comment: Thanks much.  Please vote for this answer if it helped you out.